# Undo/Redo using lists of shared_ptr

Tags: c++, list, pointers, iterator, shared-ptr

I'm trying to implement a drawing program sort of like paint. I have two std::lists which contain shared_ptrs to Shapes. One is the “Undo” linked list, the other is for “Redo.”  Before I call reset on the Shape shared_ptr, add the shared_ptr to the Undo linked list via push_back.

```
LRESULT CDrawView::OnLButtonUp(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, BOOL& bHandled)
{
   int xPos= GET_X_LPARAM(lParam);
   int yPos = GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam);
   end.X = xPos;
   end.Y = yPos;
   m_shape->setEnd(xPos,yPos);
   m_shape->Draw(m_GraphicsImage);
   Undo.push_back(m_shape);
   RedrawWindow();
return 0;
}
```

When  an Undo command is given, I grab the shared_ptr at the back of the Undo linked list and move it to the Redo linked list. Then, clear out the m_GraphicsImage to white and finally  try toiterate through the Undo list, redrawing everything.

```
LRESULT CMainFrame::OnUndo(WORD /*wNotifyCode*/, WORD /*wID*/, HWND /*hWndCtl*/, BOOL& /*bHandled*/)
{
   m_view.Redo.push_back(m_view.Undo.back()); //gets the first element that was Undo
   m_view.m_GraphicsImage.Clear(255); //Clears the board

   for(std::list<std::shared_ptr<Shape>>::iterator it = m_view.Undo.end(); it!=m_view.Undo.begin() ; it--)
   {
     it->get()->Draw(m_view.m_GraphicsImage);
   }
return 0;
}
```

I keep getting list iterator not deferencable....i'm just trying to create a simmple undo and redo

Comment: Is `draw.exe` currently executing?

Comment: it works fine without my for loop. yes it is @hmjd... My iterator makes it not compile though

Comment: If the `.exe` is running then it is not writeable. Stop the `.exe` then rebuild.

Comment: how do i stop the .exe @hmjd. I forgot to mention. this uses WTL.

Comment: Locate it in task manager and terminate it.

Comment: im still getting debug assertion failed...
list iterator not deferencable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is illegal to dereference an `end()` iterator, which is what is occurring in the first iteration of this loop:

```
for(std::list<std::shared_ptr<Shape>>::iterator it = m_view.Undo.end();
```

From the [`list::end()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/end) reference page:

> Returns an iterator to the element following the last element of the container. 
>   This element acts as a placeholder; **attempting to access it results in undefined behavior.**

Use `reverse_iterators`, [`rbegin()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/rbegin) and [`rend()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/rend), if you wish to iterate backwards:

```
for (std::list<std::shared_ptr<Shape>>::reverse_iterator i(l.rbegin());
    i != l.rend();
    i++)
{
}
```

As you have c++11 features available (`std::shared_ptr`) you can use `auto` to deduce the `iterator` type instead of explicitly typing it:

```
for (auto i(l.rbegin()); i != l.rend(); i++)
{
}
```

Comment: if i do begin and draw more than 3 lines it gets rid of all three of them...how can i fix this?

Comment: error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt>' to 'std::_List_iterator<_Mylist>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _RanIt=std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<std::tr1::shared_ptr<Shape>,std::allocator<std::tr1::shared_ptr<Shape>>>>
1>          ]
1>          and

Comment: that's what i get when i try to do reverse

Comment: Those are separate questions, and need more detail to answer than you can sensibly fit in comments. This answer is correct (remember to change the type of the iterator `i` as shown).

Comment: this is working...but how come if i draw two lines and do an undo both lines are getting deleted instead of just one